# Android cant dismiss notifications if application is not open

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am currently setting up push notifications on my Android application with **FirebaseMessagingService**. I have a very simple scenario:

1. A notification is sent to the device with the following:

   > Notification title and body text, and a HashMap of data containing a Notification type and some booking id.
   >
   > Here is how I extract this data in the Android app:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
       if (!remoteMessage.getData().isEmpty()) {

           Map<String, String> payload = remoteMessage.getData();

           String notificationType = payload.get("NOTIFICATION_TYPE");
           int bookingId = Integer.parseInt(payload.get("BOOKING_ID"));
           ...
       }
   ```
2. I then use a switch statement to perform different actions depending on the notification type:

   ```
   switch (notificationType){
               case "ALLOWED":    
                   createCheckinNotification(remoteMessage, bookingId);
                   break;
               case "HIDE_CANCEL":          
               case "MANUAL_CANCEL":   
                   Notification.dismissNotificationForBooking(getApplicationContext(), bookingId);
                   break;
           }
   ```

Now, when I call `createCheckinNotification(remoteMessage, bookingId)` I save the bookingId against the notification id which was randomly generated:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("bookings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt(String.valueOf(notification.bookingId), notification.id);
        editor.commit();
```

and when I call `Notification.dismissNotificationForBooking(getApplicationContext(), bookingId);` I check the shared preferences to get the notification id to remove it.

```
public static void dismissNotificationForBooking(Context context, int bookingId) {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("bookings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String bookingIdString = String.valueOf(bookingId);

    int notificationId = sharedPreferences.getInt(bookingIdString, -1);
    if (notificationId != -1){
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.cancel(notificationId);
    }
}
```

Now this code works perfectly fine when the application is running. However, when the application is not running or is in the background dismiss notifications never work, and i have no clue why. Also because the app isnt running im having trouble debugging the application.

**EDIT 1**
I checked the Shared Preferences with file explorer and it looks like the data isn't being saved into shared preferences when the app isnt in the foreground, but saves fine when app is open

**EDIT 2**
When my checkin code runs I added a test value into shared prefs with the following:

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("bookings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("teststring", "value");
            editor.commit();
```

When the app is in the background/not running this value is never added. Seems like the same issue with my notification id. It is not added to shared prefs if app is running in the background so when we try to dismiss the notification theres no value for the bookingId saved in shared prefs

Comment: What do you mean by the application is running?

Comment: @Ticherhaz meaning its in the foreground

Comment: did you setup your payload for data?

Comment: Yes I did, and the data in the payload is always populated it would never be empty/null. Also please refer to my EDIT 2

Comment: does `onMeessageReceived` triggered when not running?

Comment: Yes its integrated with firebase push notifications. I can even make new push notifications appear its only when sharedprefs is involved that it doesnt work

Comment: any help? Seems to be a shared prefs issue. Looks like I cant access shared prefs in the android service from OREO onwards. Any suggestions?